# динамическое изменение цены в зависимости от кол-ва товара

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

по сути, имеется онлайн-магазин с уже СУЩЕСТВУЮЩЕЙ такой же poopup-формой(она открывается при нажатии на кнопку "ВКорзину") но мне необходимо подытоживать цену на кол-во товара уже непосредственно на странице с этим товаром.
Основная цена берется из БД, естественно, есть форма input, которая увеличивает и уменьшает кол-во товара, но самой логики вычета цены от колл-ва нету(

```
                <div class="counter">
                <input type="text" value="1"/>
                </div>
```

выше идет уменьшение или увеличение товара

```
                    <span class="number">тут значение из массива данных</span>
```

а вот тут идет вывод цены на сайт

писал на php с сохранения каунтинга на сессию, считало только при перезагрузке страницы(1) и изменения были видны всем (2)

вопрос, собсна, такой: возможно ли оперировать ценой в зависимости от колличества товара(нажимая, например, на плюс и цена товара уже будет не за 1 предмет, а за два), и как это сделать ?

прошу помочь, и не кричать)

Comment: Не совсем понял задачу! Цена меняется при изменении количества товаров в самой корзине, либо же при добавлении товара в корзину?

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте!
Вот js на Juqery. Не очень понял задачу. 
Меняется цена при ручном изменении количества товара.

```
$( ".counter input[type=text]" ).change(function() {
  var price = 10; // сюда кладете цену 1 товара из БД
  var total = $(this).val()*price;
  $( ".number" ).html(total); 
});
```

Comment: .val() у span'a?

Comment: Опечатка, $( ".number" ).html(total);

Comment: если честно, немного не понял логики вывода данных из этой формы, первый раз с js, уж простите)

Comment: пардон, разобрался)

Comment: @АлексейСергеевич будут вопросы - готов ответить.

Comment: проблема в том, что у меня создается массив с информацией о товаре, как заставить js обработать массив с ценой я не знаю.

Comment: хм, проблема следующего рода, при енкоддинге json'ом цена выходит в двойных кавычках, собсна, поэтому он и не считает